# Scrolling a UIScrollView changes its subviews frames

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, autolayout

My app uses storyboards and autolayout. In a view controller I created a `UIScrollView` and added three subviews.

At run time I need to change  the sizes of the subviews and rearrange them. Initially, I rearrange them in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and it seems to work until I scroll the scroll view. Then the subview frames are changed back to the sizes that are set in IB. (I'm setting the `UIScrollView`'s content size when rearranging the views and removing all `UIViewConstraints`.)

Comment: if you need to change frames at runtime. yoiu will need to Disable "auto layout" for that view controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frames and `Auto Layout` doesn't go together, If you are using `Auto Layout` you'll need to rearrange the constrains, not the frames. While using `Auto Layout` Changing the frames will cause some weird effects and will eventually revert back to the constraints you've created in the original `UIView`.

A few solutions:

1. You can create an outlet to each constrain just like you would to a view and change its constant when needed.
2. If you are using xib you can disable `Auto Layout` in that specific xib.

Comment: First solution worked, with few constraints + few constraints with IBOutlet helped me to do exactly what i was needed, Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

i am using auto layout. and working properly. i have a uiscrollview and it contains 3-4 images. it depends to how many images there is. when i try to make fullscreen current image, i am using a functioni hope it works.its like this:

-(void) growImg {

```
if (self.growImgNeed) {

    self.Scroller.frame=CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 376);
    CGRect ViewSize = Scroller.bounds;
    for(int i=0;i< Scroller.subviews.count;i++){
        [[self.Scroller.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setSize:CGSizeMake(320, 376)];
        [[self.Scroller.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setFrame:ViewSize];
        ViewSize = CGRectOffset(ViewSize, Scroller.bounds.size.width, 0);
        }
    Scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake((Scroller.subviews.count) * Scroller.bounds.size.width, Scroller.bounds.size.height);
    self.growImgNeed=false;
}

else {
    self.Scroller.frame=CGRectMake(80, 82, 160, 188);
    CGRect ViewSize = Scroller.bounds;
    for(int i=0;i< Scroller.subviews.count;i++){
        [[self.Scroller.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setSize:CGSizeMake(160, 188)];
        [[self.Scroller.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setFrame:ViewSize];
        ViewSize = CGRectOffset(ViewSize, Scroller.bounds.size.width, 0);
    }
    Scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake((Scroller.subviews.count) * Scroller.bounds.size.width, Scroller.bounds.size.height);
    self.growImgNeed=true;

}
```

}